# How to aggregate survival type of data to single measure independent of time?

Tags: r, probability, survival, binomial-distribution

Thank you for the opportunity to ask this question. Since I do not speak fluently (still learning) the language of mathematics, I explain this in plain English. I understand this is too ideal but I hope it's sufficient.

**Explain data:** The data in the example is the distribution of failure rate (the "p") across time (the "t"). The **single explanatory variable** has 3 discrete groups (factor levels of single variable), here in `r script` as objects `(g1,g2,g3)`. The `t` is a time unit (years). The `p` here is the cumulative failure rate (n fails/n total obs.).

**Question:** I would like to have a single probability measure (the "p") for each group `(g1,g2,g3)`, rather than have for each group `(g1,g2,g3)` a multiple probability measure across time, and not a survival type (discrete) shaped data with multiple probabilities across time for each group.

**attempt** The proposed attempt to solve it without any math/statistical rigor and therefore I cannot tell if this is a sensible and correct solution.

Example:

```
# cdf for each group over time

n.g <- 10; # continuous variable split into 10 groups 
g1 <- data.frame(p=c(round(exp(seq(log(0.75), log(1), ,3)),3),rep(1,7)), t=1:n.g/n.g);
g2 <- data.frame(p=c(round(exp(seq(log(0.05), log(1), ,6)),3),rep(1,4)), t=1:n.g/n.g);
g3 <- data.frame(p=round(exp(seq(log(0.15), log(1), ,10)),3), t=1:n.g/n.g);


plot(p ~ t, data=g1, type="s", pch=19, col=1, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
points(p ~ t, data=g2, type="s", pch=19, col=2)
points(p ~ t, data=g3, type="s", pch=19, col=3)
```

[image]

```
# Question: determine single risk measure = p independent of time t (from discrete time to event series)

# attempt 

n.sim <- 1e+5;
g1.dx <- table(sample(g1$p, n.sim, replace = TRUE, prob=g1$t))/n.sim
g1.dx
g2.dx <- table(sample(g2$p, n.sim, replace = TRUE, prob=g2$t))/n.sim
g2.dx
g3.dx <- table(sample(g3$p, n.sim, replace = TRUE, prob=g3$t))/n.sim
g3.dx

# the single variable has been discretized into 3 groups and now for each group we assigned a probability measure
agg.p <- data.frame(g1.dx[length(g1.dx)],g2.dx[length(g2.dx)],g3.dx[length(g3.dx)]);
colnames(agg.p) <- c("p_g1","p_g2","p_g3");
agg.p
```

Comment: Apologies in advance for noting this but your *description* is written in R code, not plain English. As such, it is quite confusing what you are doing and how that relates to your question. My question is: the graph shows a correct left-aligned origin of data wrt time but what is the unit of analysis? In other words, do you only have 3 observations, one for each group? Or a much larger set of objects such as devices, machines or patients which comprise the groups?

Comment: Many thanks Mike for looking into this. I have now added more description to the `data` under section "Explain data:". To your question, the answer is: No, I do not have only 3 observations (the `p` value is a proportion of failed/total obs), but these are only 3 groups (factor levels of single variable). So yes the sample size its much larger, the number of patients in each group `(g1-g3)` are in sufficiently large (>1e+4).

Comment: Another question: if the time unit is in years, why does the x-axis show decimals like 0.2, 0.4, etc.? Are these expressing a percentage of a year? Multiple years? Is a plain English statement of your question something like, "Starting at time zero, what is the likelihood of a patient in one of three groups to fail (die?) by the end of the study?" Based on the chart, an unequivocal answer to this is that for the grey and red groups, that likelihood is 100%, leaving only the green group unanswered.

Comment: Sorry Mike for this incompleteness. These are 10 years, but I converted them to 1:10/10.  So the unit of x-axis always remains incremental equal units spaced unit.